# Angular ui-router reloading ng-include outside ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

Probably it's the entire layout wrong but here is my situation, I'm using a Meanjs.org stack with Angular ui-router.

I have a layout like this:

```
<div data-ng-include="'/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html'"></div>

<div id="page-content" class="clearfix" fit-height>
    <div id="wrap" data-ui-view="" class="mainview-animation"></div>
</div>
```

Now I need to reload the controller inside the header.client.view.html when I change the $state.

For example when I'm in the sign-in page and I login I need to reload the header controller, but having this it's not possible because the ui-router change only the ui-view part with the relative template:

```
// this change only ui-view, doesn't care about the ng-include before    
state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/home.client.view.html',
});
```

I found the possibility to add more ui-view to the state so I could add a ui-view2 for the header instead using the ng-include but this means having the ui-view2 on each state.

Any suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not need to "reload the controller" every time the state changes, instead make your controller react to the state change on the fly and update its properties.

Check out the ui-router [`$stateChangeSuccess` event](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

Answer (score 2):

First at all you need to listen @Matti Virkkunen
It's better to listen the state in your header's controller with "$stateChangeSuccess"

So you just have to declare a controller for your header. And inside your header controller add something like this.

```
 $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    // Do what you want for example check if the current state is home with $state.is('home');
 });
```

Do not forget to declare your controller in your template

```
<div data-ng-controller="HeaderController" data-ng-include="'/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html'"></div>

<div id="page-content" class="clearfix" fit-height>
  <div id="wrap" data-ui-view="" class="mainview-animation"></div>
</div>
```